How to manage duplicate contacts in Thunderbird?
How can duplicate contacts be merged? Ideally by the merged contact not losing any information contained in any of the duplicates, possibly with manual review of the changes beforehand?
Thunderbird 115.10.2. Some contacts are duplicates, sometimes with different information, within the same address book, while there are also duplicates between different address books.
I have been trying to use CardBook's contact duplication tool, but that seems to affect only CardBook's address book, and not the native address book. Since the address books are associated with IMAP accounts, I had thought and hoped that changes made by CardBook would be reflected everywhere those accounts are accessed. Am I missing something?
I also searched for other add-ons, but the only one found was Duplicate Contacts Manager, which hasn't been updated in a long time and is not available for Thunderbird 115.
